# xUnit test asp net core Mapper not initialized

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, xunit

I am testing this method that in the end does mapping to my DTO

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var currencies = await _repository.GetCurrencies().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (currencies.Count == 0)
                return NoContent();

            return Ok(currencies.ToDto());
        }
```

In return of this method I get the following error:

> Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Mapper not initialized.
>   Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to
>   use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you
>   do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're
>   using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you
>   pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

I use a static method to do auto mapper

```
public static List<CurrencyDTO> ToDto(this List<Currency> model)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<List<Currency>, List<CurrencyDTO>>(model);
        }
```

When I run only this test it passes but when I squeeze everyone it speaks

I tried already make a builder initialize mapper but continue error, test only passes if it is run individually

```
public class CurrenciesControllerTest
    {
        public CurrenciesControllerTest()
        {
            AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();
        }
        private Mock<IReimbursementRepository> _repository = new Mock<IReimbursementRepository>();
        [Fact]
          public async Task Should_return_all_currencies()
        {
            var mock = Currencyfactory().AsQueryable().BuildMock();
            _repository.Setup(x => x.GetCurrencies()).Returns(mock.Object);

            var controller = new CurrenciesController(_repository.Object);
            var response = await controller.Get().ConfigureAwait(false) as OkObjectResult;`enter code here`

            Assert.Equal(response.StatusCode, (int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you say _when I squeeze everyone it speaks_ do you mean something like “when I run all the tests this one throws an error”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution, configure AutoMapperConfig

```js
 public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static object thisLock = new object();
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            lock (thisLock)
            {
                AutoMapper.Mapper.Reset();
                AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { });
            }
        }
    }
}
```